# Error on record creation: nil object instead of array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, record, nested-attributes

I have a `Topic` that has many `Posts`, and accepts nested attributes for them. When I create a topic it creates a first post as well.

When `Topics#create` is called I get a `NoMethodError` when trying to evaluate `nil.[]=`, and I just can't figure out what's causing it.

The create method:

```
@forum = Forum.find params[:forum_id]
params[:topic][:post_attributes][:member_id] = current_member.id
@topic = @forum.topics.create params[:topic]
respond_with @topic, location: topic_url(@topic)
```

My new topic form:

```
- @topic.posts.build
= form_for @topic do |topic_form|
  = topic_form.label :title
  = topic_form.text_field :title
  = topic_form.fields_for :posts do |post_fields|
    = post_fields.label :content
    = post_fields.text_area :content
```

Any idea on what is wrong?

Comment: What line is the error pointing to
?

Comment: @Zabba: There is one line of code I had removed for testing before I copied it. Updated the question to include it. Error is happening on the second line.

Comment: And what are your incoming params? (They should be displayed in the error page, a bit lower down)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that it is on this line:

```
params[:topic][:post_attributes][:member_id] = current_member.id
```

You should probably update it to:

```
params[:topic][:post_attributes][0][:member_id] = current_member.id
```

or

```
params[:topic][:post_attributes].first[:member_id] = current_member.id
```

Because you are using a has_many association there is a potential for more than one post to be submitted with the topic, therefore the params for the post_attributes are actually an array.

Comment: Is there any way to simulate a `has_one` association in order to ensure only one post is ever submitted?

Comment: There are a couple ways. 1. Create a first_post attribute or has_one association of your own that you can use for this form - instead of the has_many posts association. 2. Hard-code the HTML to only allow for a single set of post-attributes - requires more manual work on your end. My suggestion would be to do what your doing now and then verify that only one post is submitted by checking the length of [:post_attributes] and making sure it's equal to 1 and not greater than 1.

Answer (score 1):

Is it a has many association for Post ?

Maybe you should try with :

```
params[:topic][:posts_attributes][0][:member_id] = current_member.id
```